Sample Complexity of BHT with varying degrees of (large) compression
In Communication-constrained hypothesis testing:
Optimality, robustness, and reverse data processing inequalities, the following (up to some mild editing to highlight my question) is established.

Corollary 3.4 (Preservation of Hellinger distance). For any $D\geq 2$, $p,q\in\Delta_k$, there exists $T:[k]\to[D]$ such that the following holds:
$$
1 \leq \inf_A\frac{H^2(p,q)}{H^2(A(p),A(q))} \leq 1800\max(1,\frac{\min(k,k')}{D}),
$$
where $k′ = \log (4/H^2(p,q))$.

Here, $\Delta_k$ is the probability simplex on finite sets with $k$ elements.
$H^2(\vec p, \vec q) :=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i\in[k]}(\sqrt{p_i}-\sqrt{q_i})^2$ is the (squared) Hellinger distance.
The notation $[k] := \{0,1,\dots,k-1\}$.
There is also a proof of tightness of the above

Lemma 3.6. There exists positive constants $c_1,\dots,c_6$ such that for $\rho\in(0,c_6)$ and $D\geq 2$, there exists $k\in[c_2\log(1/\rho),c_3\log(1/\rho)]$ and two distributions $\vec p, \vec q$ on $[k]$ such that $H^2(\vec p, \vec q)\in [c_4\rho, c_5\rho]$ and
$$
\inf_{A:[k]\to[D]} \frac{H^2(\vec p, \vec q)}{H^2(A(\vec p), A(\vec q))}\geq c_6 \frac{\max(k,k')}{D}
$$

The above can be used to reason about the sample complexity of Binary hypothesis testing, where one gets compressed samples $A(x_i)$ rather than uncompressed $x_i$.
This is because it is known that $\Theta(1/H^2(\vec p, \vec q))$ captures this aformentioned sample complexity.
E.g. the cost of binary hypothesis testing with "no compression" versus "some (parameterized by $D$)" compression.
I'm curious about the cost of varying levels of compression.
In particular, set two constants $D_1 \leq D_2$, and compare the ratio
$$
\frac{H^2(A_1(\vec p), A_2(\vec q))}{H^2(A_2(\vec p), A_2(\vec q))},
$$
where $A_1 : [k]\to[D_1]$, and $A_2: [k]\to [D_2]$.
One can leverage Corollary 3.4 to get bounds
$$
1 \leq \frac{H^2(A_1(\vec p), A_1(\vec q)}{H^2(A_2(\vec p), A_2(\vec q))} \leq 1800 \max(1,\frac{\min(k,k')}{D_2})
$$
It is not clear to me how to get an analogue of Lemma 3.6 in this setting though, e.g. if binary hypothesis testing where one heavily compresses the input (say sets $D_1 = 2$ and $D_2 = 3$) has mostly the same cost, or if there is some "threshold behavior".
Is this known (or can it be easily derived from the aformentioned Lemma 3.6?)
